# Django Rest Framework. Custom permission with JSONWebTokenAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a need to write a custom permission (deriving from `BasePermission`) for one of my endpoints where:

If the method is `POST`, it's open for everyone (e.g. returns true)..
however, if the method if `PUT` or `GET` it should be authenticated with `JSONWebTokenAuthentication` to figure out if to clear or reject the request.

Typically, I know how to add this into my `APIView` class

`authentication_classes = ([JSONWebTokenAuthentication])`

But how do I check whether the user is already authenticated with `JSONWebTokenAuthentication` in case the `HTTP` method is `PUT` or `GET` in my Custom Permission class? Is there something like `IsJSONWebTokenAuthenticated` somewhere?

Comment: you should write yor custom permission class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom permission for your view,

**permissions.py**

```
class CustomPermission(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (request.method =='POST' or (request.user and request.user.is_authenticated())):
            return True
        return False
```

Then, you need to add to your settings.py,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = { 
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':
        ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
        ('rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
         'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
         'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', ),
         }
```

Then add the permission to your permission_classes of the view,

```
from .permissions import CustomPermission

class YourView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (CustomPermission, )
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Worked perfectly.

Comment: do you have to have the default permission class be `IsAuthenticated` ? If so how do you handle views which require no authentication

Comment: You can provide `permission_classes = (AllowAny, )` in your CBV for those not requiring authentication.